# Mysql Query to Create a custom report

Tags: magento-enterprise, mysql, model

I am writing a query to export a custom report regarding sales. The following tables are in question

- sales_flat_order
- sales_flat_order_item
- sales_flat_shipment_grid

I haven't worked much with phpmyadmin since i started working with Magento. Models and collections do a pretty good job. But this time i needed some stuff real quick so thought that writing a query would be the easiest. The following query repeats some data and duplicates some rows. I am not sure why it's doing that but a person thorough with Magento would definitely know what I am talking about

```
SELECT s.increment_id, s.status, s.subtotal, s.shipping_amount, s.grand_total, s.customer_firstname, s.customer_lastname, o.name, o.sku, o.row_total, o.tax_amount, o.discount_amount, g.created_at AS Shipped_date
FROM sales_flat_order s
LEFT JOIN sales_flat_shipment_grid g ON g.order_increment_id = s.increment_id
LEFT JOIN sales_flat_order_item o ON g.order_id = o.order_id
```

Comment: what is showing duplicate

Comment: Few rows are showing as duplicate. I wanted to confirm that the query is correct.

Comment: what are you want to from this question.. Please explain why you have join `sales table with  sales_flat_shipment_grid  & sales_flat_order_item`

Comment: If you look at my select statement you'll notice what I am trying to get. I am joining the `sales_flat_shipment_grid` to get the Shipment Created date and `sales_flat_order_item` to get the item details from the order

Comment: there are duplicate records  exit in query because of an order may  be have several  `shipment &  invoice ` basic of no  of items  and its  qty.So please explain what would u want

Comment: Basically, I want to display ordered items info. Magento Order# along with all items which were ordered. So Magento order# will be on multiple rows. But the problem is, some other are displayed many time. For eg: Order# 100000300 has 4 items, so it should display 4 items. But what happens is it display 8 items, repeating the 4items twice. I am not sure why it does that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29825/discussion-between-muhammad-and-amit-bera).